# Batch open site in Google Chrome

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, google-chrome, batch-file, cmd

I want to create a link with batch using the following code.

```
explorer "http://www.mysite.com"
```

However, what are the repercussions if someone uses another browser program like Chrome?

How can I handle this so that it will work for either browser?

Answer (score 2):

Try this (command line or script):

```
start "" "http://www.mysite.com"
```

Comment: Just to expand on this answer. The start command will use whatever default program handles http urls on that computer. Which is exactly what you would want. The same would be true if you used 'start' with any type of file. It just says let Windows decide what to use.